# How can I use a sub query to count records in previous month

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like:

`+-----+------------+-----+----------+----------------+---------------------+
| id  | tid        | pid | amt      | transtime      | DateCreated         |
+-----+------------+-----+----------+----------------+---------------------+
| 784 | LDC3N0JF1Z | 784 | 300.0000 | 20170412174304 | 2017-04-12 17:43:42 |
| 783 | LDC6MWNHO8 | 783 | 500.0000 | 20170412124952 | 2017-05-12 12:50:15 |
| 782 | LDB1MPK8BP | 782 | 200.0000 | 20170411192815 | 2017-05-11 19:28:19 |
| 781 | LDA2MAUW08 | 781 | 200.0000 | 20170410174635 | 2017-07-10 17:47:01 |
| 780 | LDA8MAMQT4 | 780 | 200.0000 | 20170410173245 | 2017-04-10 17:33:19 |
+-----+------------+-----+----------+----------------+---------------------+`

I want a query to give me results that look like this. The results that I want look like this.

```
id|tid        |this_month_amount|amount_previous_month |amount_difference
------------------------------------------------------------------
1 |LDC3N0JF1Z |300              | 700                  |400
```

I have also attempted the problem. This is what I have.

`select payment.id,payment.tid,payment.DateCreated as dc,payment.amount as this_month_amount, inner join
(SELECT sum(amount) as t2 sum group by amount from payments where DateCreated= DATEADD(mm,-1,dc))subquery on payments.id = subquery.id order by id desc limit 5
)`

So the query should select amount from the month and then amounts from previous months and then show the difference in the field called `amount_difference`

Its wrong, so after trying a lot, I want some help from you people. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the values from the current month:

```
select tid, sum(amount) as this_month,
from t
where date_created >= curdate() + interval (1 - day(curdate()) day and
      date_created < curdate() + interval (1 - day(curdate()) day + interval 1 month
group by tid;
```

Note that this carefully uses functions only on the current date, so MySQL could use an index on `date_create` if one were available.

To get the amount from the previous month, let's extend this using conditional aggregation:

```
select tid,
       sum(case when month(date_created) = month(curdate()) then amount end) as this_month,
       sum(case when month(date_created) <> month(curdate()) then amount end) as last_month,
       (sum(case when month(date_created) = month(curdate()) then amount end) -
        sum(case when month(date_created) <> month(curdate()) then amount end)
       ) as diff
from t
where date_created >= curdate() + interval (1 - day(curdate()) day -
```

interval 1 month and
          date_created < curdate() + interval (1 - day(curdate()) day + interval 1 month
    group by tid;

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linnof . Took me some time to adapt your solution for my application but now it works :)